# No access to the view from within switch android

Tags: android

I used a very similar piece of code as below to `setOnClickListener` on a button and the view was passed through.

```
((Switch) convertView.findViewById(R.id.push_switch)).setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
   @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
     if(rowItem.getPush().equals("N")){
         ((Switch) convertView.findViewById(R.id.push_switch)).toggle();
         rowItem.setPush("Y");
     }
     else if(rowItem.getPush().equals("Y")){
         ((Switch) convertView.findViewById(R.id.push_switch)).toggle();
         rowItem.setPush("N");
     }
   }
});
```

Within the code above, there view isn't passed through so how can I access it to change where I have put `convertView`.

A side query that isn't crucial to the question is why the first line of this was cast to (Switch) when that didn't happen on a button. Just intrigued on that one!

Thanks :)

Comment: "...view isn't passed through..." - `compoundButton` is the Switch.

Comment: I've never used a compoundbutton before so am maybe misunderstanding what it is. If I have a switch, I need to activate a callback on the state of it changing. Would I use what I have to do that? As I need to access the switch which is within the parent of this?

Comment: `CompoundButton` is the base class for the `Switch` class. In the listener method, cast `compoundButton` to `Switch`, instead of trying `findViewById()` on the `convertView`. This will be the `Switch` object that's receiving the event.

Comment: Just discovered that as you wrote it! Do you want to answer the question or shall I delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Mike M commented, compoundButton is the Switch. The callback method `onCheckedChanged` is passing you a reference to the CompoundButton which triggered the callback...in this case, your Switch.

You can do this:

```
compoundButton.toggle();
```

Comment: It seems this has now prevented my switch from changing position! It's stuck on off now!

Comment: You probably didn't want to toggle it—I was just following your code. Logically, what your code was saying was "When the switch is toggled, toggle it back"

Comment: Yeah, I've just debugged through it and realised that I don't need it to toggle as the user is physically toggling it themselves! Thanks anyway!